# Check serverlist offline / online PHP

Tags: php, offline, status

i try to make a script to check if my server are online or offline:

```
<?

    $server = "12.34.56.78";

    $check = @fsockopen($server, 22);

    if ($check) {
        @fclose($check);
        echo "online";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "offline";
    }

?>
```

so this script works, but how can i make the script that i can check more than one ip address?

Greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$servers = Array("server1", "server2");

foreach ($servers as $server) {
  // same as before
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkServerOnline($server, $port = 22) {
    $check = @fsockopen($server, $port);
    if ($check) {
        @fclose($check);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Then you can call it with various server-port-combinations.

Answer (score 1):

There is [open source tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) for this readily available.

Check out [Nagios - The Industry Standard In Open Source Monitoring](http://www.nagios.org/):

> **Nagios is a powerful monitoring system that enables organizations to identify and resolve IT infrastructure problems before they affect critical business processes.**
>
> Nagios monitors your entire IT infrastructure to ensure systems, applications, services, and business processes are functioning properly. In the event of a failure, Nagios can alert technical staff of the problem, allowing them to begin remediation processes before outages affect business processes, end-users, or customers. With Nagios you'll never be left having to explain why a unseen infrastructure outage hurt your organization's bottom line.