# Best way of detecting if a web service is online / offline with PHP

Tags: php

I've found various methods:

- [Check serverlist offline / online PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404885/check-serverlist-offline-online-php)
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/

But was curious on the best / most efficient to use or any alternatives.

I'm using the yahoo currency API for my script and I want to add a fallback API incase the yahoo currency goes down. **How can I detect this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if the service goes down after you check if its up but before you use it?

Instead, just call the api. If you do not get a result, then use your fall back method.

Also, just because a server is online doesn't mean that the services on it are not in some way broken. The only real way to test it is to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Call the Yahoo API using the Curl library, which allows you to specify a very short timeout, such as 3 seconds.

If it doesn't respond within 3 seconds, switch to your other fallback API.

There is no more reliable way to check if something is online than to actually try and use it. Any communication from your server to yahoo's server should take less than half a second, so if it still hasn't responded after 3 seconds then something is very wrong.